# r droplevel in big datafiles

Tags: r, csv

This is just an small example of the table now :) (Thanks to the community in here that help me so much)

```
Protocol  a0:48:1c:df:1b:1b 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.11 Vmware_1f:29:b7 fe80::16e:8d02:e94e:396f 
TCP           1                0           0                  1                   1
HTTP          1                1           1                  1                   1
BROWSER       1                0           1                  1                   1 
ARP           1                1           1                  0                   1
ICMPv3        1                1           1                  1                   1
```

How can i delete the column without hard coding the IPs that i wanted in a big data files which there are over alots of IPs like the table shown above that i want to remove

```
Protocol   10.0.0.11 10.0.0.11
TCP         0           0                  
HTTP        1           1                 
BROWSER     0           1                
ARP         1           1                
ICMPv3      1           1
```

Comment: You already asked this question before. Why can't you use the answers already provided? What's wrong with `df[, grep("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$", names(df))]` for example??

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry about it, but i tried it , the table delete every source ip including those IPs that i want to have

Comment: I've just realised my mistake because i never convert matrix to dataframe, Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Protocol  a0:48:1c:df:1b:1b 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.11 Vmware_1f:29:b7 fe80::16e:8d02:e94e:396f 
TCP           1                0           0                  1                   1
HTTP          1                1           1                  1                   1
BROWSER       1                0           1                  1                   1 
ARP           1                1           1                  0                   1
ICMPv3        1                1           1                  1                   1", header = T, check.names = FALSE)
```

Solution (mainly attributed to @akruns answer on your previous question)

```
df[, grep("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$", names(df))]
#   10.0.0.11 10.0.0.11.1
# 1         0           0
# 2         1           1
# 3         0           1
# 4         1           1
# 5         1           1
```

Comment: `df[grepl("[.]", names(df))]` also gets 'er done and it's a bit cleaner